# VBA solution too long time calculation of formulas when running a macro

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a 13 MB file. When I run my macro it calculates the first rows in 3 different worksheets and then I use the `AutoFill` technique to next to 6000 rows and it takes too long time, something between 7-8 minutes.

Most of the formulas are simple and should not take to long time, in my opinion. 
Someone has solution to my problem? Maybe a way that the calculation itself will happen in the module and in the workbook we will see just the result, the values?

My code starts with a `userform` and then calls to a module, that takes most of the time that the macro runs. as I said each of the 3 sheets includes next to 6000 rows. I want that in the end in the worksheet I will see just the `values`.

```
Sub Formulas()

Call Columns

LR = VacationWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With VacationWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],VacationWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R2C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],VacationWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R5C5)"
    'Column F
        MyCol = .Range("F2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-5],VacationWS!RC[-5],Visual!C[3],Lists!R2C3,Visual!C[2],Lists!R2C5)"
    'Column G
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    'Column H
        MyCol = .Range("H2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-7],VacationWS!RC[-7],Visual!C[1],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C,Lists!R5C5)"
    'Column I
        .Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:I2").AutoFill Destination:=VacationWS.Range("D2:I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:I1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

End With


With IllnessWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],IllnessWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R3C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],IllnessWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R6C5)"
    'Column F
        MyCol = .Range("F2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-5],IllnessWS!RC[-5],Visual!C[3],Lists!R2C3,Visual!C[2],Lists!R3C5)"
    'Column G
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    'Column H
        MyCol = .Range("H2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-7],IllnessWS!RC[-7],Visual!C[1],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C,Lists!R6C5)"
    'Column I
        .Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:I2").AutoFill Destination:=IllnessWS.Range("D2", "I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:I1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

    'Delete what is equal to 90 or more in column H
    .Range("$A$1:$I$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=90", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A2:I" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

End With


With HealingWS
    'Column D
        MyCol = .Range("D2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-3],HealingWS!RC[-3],Visual!C[5],Lists!R3C3,Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C5)"
    'Column E
        MyCol = .Range("E2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthBefore - MyCol
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-4],HealingWS!RC[-4],Visual!C[4],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[3],Lists!R7C5)"
    'Column F
        .Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
    'Column G
        MyCol = .Range("G2").Column
        ColumnSpace = MonthCol - MyCol
        .Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Visual!C[" & ColumnSpace & "],Visual!C[-6],HealingWS!RC[-6],Visual!C[2],Lists!R4C3,Visual!C[1],Lists!R7C5)"
    'Column H
        .Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-2]"

    'Delete unnecessary rows
    .Range("D2:H2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("D2:H" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$H$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0"
     On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:H" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData

'Specific for June in HealingWS (Goes to Null)
    With Lists
        If MonthName = .Range("A7").Value Then
            HealingWS.Range("E2").Value = 0
            HealingWS.Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End With
End With

'January formulas change
If MonthName = Lists.Range("A2").Value Then
    With VacationWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],VacationWS!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R5C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=VacationWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With IllnessWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],îçìä!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R6C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=IllnessWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With

    With HealingWS
        .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(December!C[7],December!C[-4],HealingWS!RC[-4],December!C[4],Lists!R4C3,December!C[3],Lists!R7C5)"
        .Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=HealingWS.Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: As you've problem with the formula,  not just with the code itself,  it'd be beneficial to post sample data and formulas too.  That would help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't see any code where you turn off the display of the data, that generally speeds things up.

Comment: Fully agree with @pacmaninbw here, that's usually the first thing to do when you run into performance problems with VBA in Excel.

Comment: I have displays of screen updating, events and alerts in the start of the code that is not here

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Formulas in Mass, do something with the **`Application.Calculation`**.

```
Sub Formulas()
    Dim lCalcMode As Long

    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation ' Store Current Calculation Mode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Change to manual Calculation

    Call Columns
    '... Your orginal Codes before End Sub ...

    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode ' Restore Calculation Mode
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A calculation took place when related Ranges has changes if Calculation is Auto/SemiAuto. That should be the reason your code took so long to complete.